# How to redirect file not found error on wordpress

Tags: wordpress, nginx, http-status-code-404

I have a wordpress site in which I want to redirect all the **FILE NOT FOUND 404s**.

> example : wwww.xyz.com/abc.php
>   if abc.php does not exist on the server it should be redirected to home page.

I have successfully redirected page not found 404s but having issues in redirecting this one. Can it be done using any plugin?

Answer (score 0):

Why not create a 404.php page within your theme and then put in the following code to redirect?

```
<?php   
   header( 'Location: http://www.yoursite.com/new_page.html' ) ;
?>
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: I have already created a 404.php .. but it does not show up when I request for a file that is not available on the server.

Comment: So when you visit, for example, wwww.xyz.com/abc.php, what do you see?

Comment: I see 404 not found and below it nginx. The problem is it is not redirecting when I add .php at the end..

Comment: Have you checked your error.log to see if everything has been set up correctly?

Answer (score 0):

For redirection there is a nice WordPress plugin which can do that quite simply - https://wordpress.org/plugins/simple-301-redirects/

But if the issue is that the webserver is showing the default 404 page and not the one within WordPress you should check if .htaccess is present, mod_rewrite is installed . Are the existing pages in WP redirecting properly?